# transform JSON with Jolt transform

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON looking like this:

```json
[
  {
    "latency": 9,
    "tx-data-pkts": "14709",
    "rx-data-pkts": "2809",
    "entry-time": 1627585211218,
    "sla-class-index": "0",
    "index": "0"
  },
  {
    "latency": 9,
    "tx-data-pkts": "15418",
    "rx-data-pkts": "3306",
    "entry-time": 1627585211218,
    "sla-class-index": "0",
    "index": "1"
  },
  {
    "latency": 9,
    "tx-data-pkts": "15108",
    "rx-data-pkts": "3485",
    "entry-time": 1627585211218,
    "sla-class-index": "0",
    "index": "0"
  },
  {
    "latency": 9,
    "tx-data-pkts": "15311",
    "rx-data-pkts": "3852",
    "entry-time": 1627585211218,
    "sla-class-index": "0",
    "index": "1"
  }
]
```

I need to bring myself only the objects from the array with *index* **0** such as

```json
[
  {
    "latency": 9,
    "tx-data-pkts": "14709",
    "rx-data-pkts": "2809",
    "entry-time": 1627585211218,
    "sla-class-index": "0",
    "index": "0"
  },
  {
    "latency": 9,
    "tx-data-pkts": "15108",
    "rx-data-pkts": "3485",
    "entry-time": 1627585211218,
    "sla-class-index": "0",
    "index": "0"
  }
]
```

Please help me

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use successive **shift** transformations; combine the common grouped objects with the keys by using `"@(0,index)"` value within the first one, and then pick the zero valued keys from them only such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "@(0,index)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```